# Java multithreading: positioning of methods

Tags: java, multithreading

I've written a plugin for a program which logs the activity of the user. If the user presses a button and thus triggering an action, some stuff should be written to the database. This process should run in parallel because it shouldnt delay the triggered action:

```
if (con != null) {
        SmartClientKernel.addPooledTask(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ActionDispatcher.getInstance().addDispatchExtension(new IDispatchExtension() {
                    @Override
                    public void preprocessActionExecution(RPAction action) {
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        Date startTime = cal.getTime();
                        String actionName = action.getName();
                        java.sql.Timestamp sqlTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(startTime.getTime());
                        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
                        PreparedStatement statement;
                        try {
                            statement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + tableName
                                    + " (ID, USERNAME, SESSIONID, PROJECTNAME, STARTTIME, ACTIONTYPE, ACTIONNAME) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                            statement.setString(1, id.toString());
                            statement.setString(2, userName);
                            statement.setString(3, sessionId);
                            statement.setString(4, projectName);
                            statement.setTimestamp(5, sqlTime);
                            statement.setString(6, "Action");
                            statement.setString(7, actionName);
                            statement.execute();
                            statement.close();
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            Log.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Actually, it works fine, but I'm wondering if the programming style is ok that way because I could move the block:

```
SmartClientKernel.addPooledTask(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
```

down into the method preprocessActionExecution() which also seems to work.

What do you guys think?

**Update:**
Thank u guys for your feedback!

Comment: I would suggest to separate the DB code from the thread. Decouple the DB stuffs from other functional aspects for easy maintenance.

Comment: What do the methods `SmartClientKernel.addPooledTask` and `ActionDispatcher.getInstance().addDispatchExtension` - do you have any documentation for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like the way you do that, it's another way:

```
anyClassMethod() {
    if (con != null) {
        SmartClientKernel.addPooledTask(new MyRunnable(con, tableName, userName, sessionId, projectName));
    }
}

private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    Connection con;
    String tableName, userName, sessionId, projectName;

    MyRunnable(Connection con, String tableName, String userName, String sessionId, String projectName) {
        this.con = con;
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ActionDispatcher.getInstance().addDispatchExtension(new MyIDispatchExtension(con, tableName, userName, sessionId, projectName));
    }
}

private class MyIDispatchExtension (extends or implements) IDispatchExtension {

    Connection con;
    String tableName, userName, sessionId, projectName;

    public MyIDispatchExtension(Connection con, String tableName, String userName, String sessionId, String projectName) {
        this.con = con;
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }

    @Override
    public void preprocessActionExecution(RPAction action) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date startTime = cal.getTime();
        String actionName = action.getName();
        java.sql.Timestamp sqlTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(startTime.getTime());
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        PreparedStatement statement;
        try {
            statement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + tableName
                    + " (ID, USERNAME, SESSIONID, PROJECTNAME, STARTTIME, ACTIONTYPE, ACTIONNAME) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            statement.setString(1, id.toString());
            statement.setString(2, userName);
            statement.setString(3, sessionId);
            statement.setString(4, projectName);
            statement.setTimestamp(5, sqlTime);
            statement.setString(6, "Action");
            statement.setString(7, actionName);
            statement.execute();
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have always felt that *if a section of code **could** have its own name then it **should** have its own name*.

Or, put another way, *if it looks like a class and acts like a class it **should** be a class*.

So - in answer to your question - In my opinion each of those anonymous inner classes should be distinct classes in their own right. They don't need to be public classes though, they would be fine as `static` inners but they should be factored out and have a name.

Also - your prepared statement should be prepared elsewhere. Preparing it in-line with its use is a waste of time.